# open new silverlight window when button click

Tags: silverlight, window

I created a Silverlight window and I want it to appear when I press a button.  How can
I do that? It doesn't has a "show" method...

Comment: i need it to be open in a new adrress..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a new address in a new window use:-

```
 HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("the address here"), "_blank");
```

Comment: i wrote HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost:52878/DoNationFinalTestPage.aspx#/jjj"), "Organiztrion_info_from_toolTip");  is the window that i built, but it opens the application again in a new window and not the "Organiztrion_info_from_toolTip" window

Comment: @aharont: You say 'not the "Organiztrion_info_from_toolTip" window' as though it already exists.  That being the case with what URL did you open it in the first place?

Comment: the Organiztrion_info_from_toolTip is a silverlight window that i created and i wnat it to be open in a new window..
what do you mean "did you open it in the first place"?

Comment: @aharont:  Silverlight doesn't have true windows, like I've said in several places now edit your question to include the relevant chucks of code and Xaml you are currently using.  Your responses to comments and answers have been ambiguous and contradictory.  The best way to bring clarity to your question is by showing much more detail about what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

see:
Silverlight Simplified MVVM Modal Popup
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/MVVMPopUp.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to browse to a new silverlight application hosted in another html page you should use the [NavigationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice%28VS.95%29.aspx) class to accomplish that.

If you on the other hand want to display another view defined in your silverlight application then you should do something like this [Silverlight 3 Navigation](http://www.davidpoll.com/2009/07/12/silverlight-3-navigation-navigating-to-pages-in-referenced-assemblies/).