# Forcing links in an SSRS report to open in a new window from within silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have an **SSRS report** embedded within a **silverlight** application and I want the links in that report to open in a **new tab**.

I already tried the below and they both didn't work :

- making the link javascript:void(window.open('http://wwww.google.com')) (It just doesn't execute javascript from within silverlight but when I preview the report in Visual Studio it works)
  [image]
- adding target='_blank' in the href tag
  [image]
- Adding this parameter at the end &rc:LinkTarget=_blank (It opens in the same window)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: My gut tells me that this is probably a Silverlight-specific issue. Have you taken a look at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743361/open-new-silverlight-window-when-button-click

Comment: Sorry but I'm a bit new to SSRS, where can I put that code so that when I click on one of my fields it executes?

Comment: I don't have access to the silverlight application code so it has to be done from the SSRS report.

Comment: I'd give it a shot in the URL of the Action tab in the properties window for the text box you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve in Code behind

```
 System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(
   new Uri("http://silverlight.net"),
   "_blank", "height=300,width=600,top=100,left=100");
```

Src: MSDN

OR

Don't use href="javascript:void"

It means people without javascript cannot use the link. Use something like this instead.

Then add this to the head of your page

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
}
 </script>
  <body>
 <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">click here</a>
 </body>
```

Comment: I don't have access to the silverlight application code so it has to be done from the SSRS report.

Comment: @SuzanBalaa Does the above solution solve ur problem.

Comment: no because javascript is not executing within silverlight. Its working in Visual Studio preview but when its included in my application it's not working.

Comment: What is not working. My code should open it in new window.If you are including it in the aspx page( which is the page which hosts the silverlight plug-in ) or XAML page in the application.

Comment: Its an aspx page that contains the silverlight app and in it theres like a webview for my report.

Comment: Does ur solution have only one ASPX page which loads the plugin or you have multiple ASPX page for each silverlight module application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73811/discussion-between-user2526236-and-suzan-balaa).